# I created a login page and I need to add these things to my username. how i validate my form in flutter

Tags: flutter

Minimum 1 alphabetic
Minimum 1 number
Allow only Character (_)

its failed

```
 Pattern pattern = r'^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[_]).{8,}$';
RegExp regex = new RegExp(pattern);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check out this example that i have created :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  TextEditingController userName = TextEditingController();

  FocusNode usernameFocus = new FocusNode();
  String errorText;
  bool _isValid = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    userName.addListener(() {
      String pattern = r'^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[_]).{8,}$';
      RegExp regExp = new RegExp(pattern);

      if (userName.text.isEmpty) {
        setState(() {
          errorText = 'Field cannot be empty';
        });
      } else {
        if (!regExp.hasMatch(userName.text)) {
          print('The does not  matches the requirement');
          setState(() {
            // here you can add you text
            errorText =
                'Minimum 1 Capital letter, 1 small letter and 1 number and _';
            _isValid = false;
          });
        } else {
          print('the value matches');
          setState(() {
            errorText = null;
            _isValid = true;
          });
        }
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
            child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
              child: TextField(
                focusNode: usernameFocus,
                decoration: new InputDecoration(
                  errorText: errorText,
                  prefixIcon: Icon(
                    Icons.supervised_user_circle,
                    color: Color(0xFF282858),
                  ),
                  labelText: "UserName",
                  labelStyle: TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: "Poppins-Medium",
                      color: usernameFocus.hasFocus
                          ? Colors.grey[600]
                          : Colors.grey[600]),
                  fillColor: Colors.white,
                  focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey[400], width: 2.0),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                  ),
                  border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                    borderSide:
                        new BorderSide(color: Colors.grey[400], width: 2.0),
                  ),
                  //fillColor: Colors.green
                ),
                controller: userName,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
              ),
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text('Login'),
              onPressed: () {
                print(_isValid);

                if (!_isValid) {
                  return;
                }
                print('validation sucess');
              },
            )
          ],
        )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use a validator on your [Textfield](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField-class.html). You would add a condtion in the validator function to check if it's false and returns the error meessage that you would like the user to see.

You can either validate by using autovalidate: true, or you can do it manualy by using .currentState.validate() on your form before saving.

so your code could look something like this

```
validator: (value) {
  final alphanumeric = RegExp(YOUR_REGEX_HERE);
  if (!alphanumeric.hasMatch(value)) return 'YOUR_ERROR_MESSAGE';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library

pubspec.yaml

`flutter_form_builder: ^3.7.3`

Code will be like this:

GlobalKey _addextKey = GlobalKey();

```
       FormBuilder(
        key: _addextKey,
        child: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
           TextFormField(
            textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
            style: textStyle,
            controller: _NameauthController,
         // ignore: missing_return
            validator: FormBuilderValidators.required(),
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: 'name',
                hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0),
                labelStyle: textStyle,
                errorStyle:
                    TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontSize: 12.0),
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0))),
            keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
          ),
         ]);),
```